Is it possible to create to an EditText which doesn't wrap lines
I would like have an EditText widget input text in the following way


Long sentence without wrapping
Another long sentence without wrapping
etc


I need to enable both horizontal and vertical scrolling in the EditText
Setting single line in the EditText attributes Results in 1 line input but I would like multilines
Do I need to chain multiple EditText to achieve this or can I achieve this with just one EditText
My current EditText has the following XML Attributes
<com.binclab.mqlide.CodeEditor
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="6"
        android:maxLength="2000"/>


How would a new line of text be triggered in your EditText? By pressing "enter", by some character sequence (a period, for instance) or other means?

by pressing enter

Take a look at this answer. I did a quick test and it seems to work but you'll need to give it a try to see if it is a solution for you. I am not sure why it works. If this doesn't work for you and you can't find another solution, you might want to consider offering a bounty.

Ok so all I had to do put EditText in a HorizontalScrollView
